# How to convert this for() and while() loops into assembly

Tags: for-loop, assembly, while-loop, x86, masm

int array_list[] = {10, 11, 13, 18, 21, 23, 24, 17, 45};

int array_size = sizeof array_list / sizeof sample;

int index = 0; // index for while loop

int sum = 0; // accumulate the result

`for (current_size = array_size ; current_size > 0 ; current_size--)
{

```
 while ( index < current_size)
{ 
           if( array_list[index] is even ) 
           { 
                 sum += array_list[index]; 
           } 
           index += 1; 
  }
```

} `

After converted, store the answer in the sum variable

So I have to convert it into x86 assembly language, and this is what I got so far

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: DWORD

.data
    sum DWORD 0
    array_list DWORD 10,11,13,18,21,23,24,17,45
    array_size = ($ - array_list) / TYPE array_list


.code
main PROC
    mov eax, 0        ; sum
    mov esi, 0        ; index
    mov ecx, array_size

    L1:
                dec ecx
        cmp esi, ecx
        jl L2
        jmp L5
    
    L2:
        cmp esi, ecx
        jl L3
        jmp L4

    L3:
        cmp array_list[esi], array_list[esi%2]
        add eax, array_list[esi]
        jmp L4
    L4:
        add esi, 1
        jmp L1
    L5:
        mov sum, eax
    


    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

For the array_size, I was trying to make sure that it is 40/4 = 10
I do not understand or know how to the for loop, so the first loop must be wrong what I wrote there.
Also, how do you do the if, where it said array_list[index] is even. Do I also need to declare the sample? Cuz it is used for the array_size. I really need help because I did not understand :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic pattern equivalence for a for-loop is as follows:

C for-loop

```
for ( init; test; incr ) {
    <loop-body>
}
```

C while-loop

```
init;
while ( test ) {
    <loop-body>
    incr;
}
```

That first loop in the assembly is following some different basic form: it has relocated the `incr;` portion in relation to the `<loop-body>`.

Surely you can see that in comparison with the following pattern:

```
init;
while ( test ) {
    incr;
    <loop-body>
}
```

that `<loop-body>` will see a different value for `current_size` each iteration (off by 1 increment, here -1) than in the C code, so it won't run the same as the C code, if that variable is ever consulted in the `<loop-body>`.

---

The `test` condition to continue the outer for in the assembly doesn't reflect the > 0 in the C code.

---

The % in the assembly code is doing array[index%2] whereas in the C code it is doing array[index]%2, which are clearly different concepts, so that wouldn't run the same (even if it were allowed like that).

---

Of course, x86 cannot do that compare instruction, because of the dual memory references.  x86 requires one operand in register in order for the other to be a memory operand.

But that C code doesn't even require two array references there.  Just one and than an even test on its value.

---

The C code requires an if-then which is missing in the assembly.

---

Let's convert the following while-loop (which matches the for-loop construct):

```
init;
while ( test ) {
    <loop-body>
    incr;
}
```

To assembly's if-goto-label style:

```
    init;
loop1:
    if ( ! test ) goto endLoop1;
    <loop-body>
    incr;
    goto loop1;
endLoop1:
```

Comment: Does `array_list[esi%2]` even assemble? I wasn't aware you could do that. To be fair I've only ever used 16-bit x86.

Comment: @puppydrum64, no, it won't.